# Play Default sound after Timer

Tags: android

I'm am trying to make my App play a Default android
Sound Once my timer has counted down.

I have searched through numerous articles on here,
and the code i have come up with is...

```
 public void playAlertSound(int sound){        
        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), sound);  
        mp.start(); 
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
        {              @Override             public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) { 
            mp.release();            
            }        
        }); 
    }
```

And This is called after the timer has ended by using -

```
playAlertSound(R.raw.beep1);
```

However beep1 is obviously not a default sound.
This is probably a file someone has added to their project.

Where do i add an mp3 file called beep1.mp3 in my project so the
above line will work?

Or is there a default sound i can call??

Any help much appreciated..

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add beep1.mp3 file in `raw` folder in your project.

means `create raw folder in res for that right click on res and create folder raw.`
In that place your `beep1.mp3` file.

Hope it helps.